# How to create ComponentResourceKey via code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

how can  i write below code via code behind.

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}, GrayForegroundStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FF333333" />
</Style>
```

here is what i m doint.

```
void ApplyRecordAreaStyle()
{
    Style recordstyle = new Style(typeof(DataRecordCellArea));

    recordstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataRecordCellArea.BackgroundAlternateProperty, SelectedBackground));
    recordstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataRecordCellArea.ForegroundAlternateStyleProperty, ????????));

    xamGrid.FieldLayoutSettings.DataRecordCellAreaStyle = recordstyle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value für the alternate properties are brushes.

For example:

```
recordstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataRecordCellArea.ForegroundAlternateStyleProperty, Brushes.Red));
```

Any brush is possible. You can not only use a solid brush like shown in my example, you could also use a gradient brush.